# Parallel asynchronous Ajax requests using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'd like to update a page based upon the results of multiple ajax/json requests. Using jQuery, I can "chain" the callbacks, like this very simple stripped down example:

```
$.getJSON("/values/1", function(data) {
  // data = {value: 1}
  var value_1 = data.value;

  $.getJSON("/values/2", function(data) {
    // data = {value: 42}
    var value_2 = data.value;

    var sum = value_1 + value_2;

    $('#mynode').html(sum);
  });

});
```

However, this results in the requests being made serially. I'd much rather a way to make the requests in parallel, and perform the page update after all are complete. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 109, accepted):

Try this solution, which can support any specific number of parallel queries:

```
var done = 4; // number of total requests
var sum = 0;

/* Normal loops don't create a new scope */
$([1,2,3,4,5]).each(function() {
  var number = this;
  $.getJSON("/values/" + number, function(data) {
    sum += data.value;
    done -= 1;
    if(done == 0) $("#mynode").html(sum);
  });
});
```

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, you are the author of 'jQuery In Action' ?

Comment: I went with something similar to yours and agilefall's:

var results = {};
var requests = 0;
 
var urls = ["values/1", "values/2", "values/3"];
 
$.each(urls, function(url) {
  $.getJSON(url, function(data) {
    results[url] = data.value;
    ++requests;
 
 
    if (requests == 3) {
      $('#mynode').html( results[urls[0]] / results[urls[1]] * results[urls[2]]);
    }
  });
});

Comment: I've done something similar to this. In the end, I did consolidate my request. But it's good to know how to do this just in case. I displayed a progress bar, which works well in this case because the code is callback-driven. Just use 100*((4-done)/4) in this case for the percentage done.

Comment: I tried the suggested solution and it didn't seem to work for me.  What happened was that only the last request got a response, the other 4 didn't. Any ideas?  I ran it on a LAMP stack.

Comment: Looks like code inside "if" could be executed multiple times. Also, is "done -= 1" atomic ?

Comment: The calls are asynchronous but javascript is still single threaded. There's no race condition because only one function runs at a time and all operations are atomic

Comment: @YehudaKatz I need to make 12 ajax calls simultaneously on the page load..It seems like one response is being copied into another for some. Is this due to browser limitations of number of concurrent calls?

Comment: Should this maybe better read: ```var someArray = [1,2,3,4,5];
var done = someArray.length; // number of total requests
var sum = 0;

/* Normal loops don't create a new scope */
$(someArray).each(function() {
  var number = this;
  $.getJSON("/values/" + number, function(data) {
    sum += data.value;
    done -= 1;
    if(done == 0) $("#mynode").html(sum);
  });
});```?

Comment: Although the answer is clever in its way, it hides the serious drawback which was mentioned by others in their comments, as well. Namely, the code is not thread-safe. The same function deals with the counters, to determine when all the requests have been done, but the function could be called asynchronously in the future (JS is steering in that direction anyway), so the code will fail immediately. This is not an example of a best-practice and future-proof code.

Answer (score 125):

jQuery [$.when()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/) and [$.done()](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.done/) are exactly what you need:

```
$.when($.ajax("/page1.php"), $.ajax("/page2.php"))
  .then(myFunc, myFailure);
```

Comment: +1 I'd heard somewhere that promises don't compose well... Apparently I need to forget that!

Comment: No offense, but isn't this answer by far superior to the one of @yehuda-katz? (Given that this works)

Comment: This answer isn't clear on how to access the data after the ajax calls complete. What is being passed to myFunc and how do I access the calls?

Comment: example with myFunc and myFailure => https://codepen.io/jacobgoh101/pen/YaJOzx?editors=0010

Answer (score 12):

**Run multiple AJAX requests in parallel**

When working with APIs, you sometimes need to issue multiple AJAX requests to different endpoints. Instead of waiting for one request to complete before issuing the next, you can speed things up with jQuery by requesting the data in parallel, by using jQuery's `$.when()` function:

**JS**

```
$.when($.get('1.json'), $.get('2.json')).then(function(r1, r2){
   console.log(r1[0].message + " " + r2[0].message);
});
```

The callback function is executed when both of these GET requests finish successfully. `$.when()` takes the promises returned by two `$.get()` calls, and constructs a new promise object. The `r1` and `r2` arguments of the callback are arrays, whose first elements contain the server responses.

Answer (score 9):

Here's my attempt at directly addressing your question

Basically, you just build up and AJAX call stack, execute them all, and a provided function is called upon completion of all the events - the provided argument being an array of the results from all the supplied ajax requests.

Clearly this is early code - you could get more elaborate with this in terms of the flexibility.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://jqueryjs.googlecode.com/files/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

var ParallelAjaxExecuter = function( onComplete )
{
  this.requests = [];
  this.results = [];
  this.onComplete = onComplete; 
}

ParallelAjaxExecuter.prototype.addRequest = function( method, url, data, format )
{
  this.requests.push( {
      "method"    : method
    , "url"       : url
    , "data"      : data
    , "format"    : format
    , "completed" : false
  } )
}

ParallelAjaxExecuter.prototype.dispatchAll = function()
{
  var self = this;
  $.each( self.requests, function( i, request )
    {
    request.method( request.url, request.data, function( r )
    {
      return function( data )
      {
        console.log
        r.completed = true;
        self.results.push( data );
        self.checkAndComplete();
      }
    }( request ) )
  } )
}

ParallelAjaxExecuter.prototype.allRequestsCompleted = function()
{
  var i = 0;
  while ( request = this.requests[i++] )
  {
    if ( request.completed === false )
    {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
},

ParallelAjaxExecuter.prototype.checkAndComplete = function()
{
  if ( this.allRequestsCompleted() )
  {
    this.onComplete( this.results );
  }
}

var pe = new ParallelAjaxExecuter( function( results )
{
  alert( eval( results.join( '+' ) ) );
} );

pe.addRequest( $.get, 'test.php', {n:1}, 'text' );
pe.addRequest( $.get, 'test.php', {n:2}, 'text' );
pe.addRequest( $.get, 'test.php', {n:3}, 'text' );
pe.addRequest( $.get, 'test.php', {n:4}, 'text' );

pe.dispatchAll();

</script>
```

here's test.php

```
<?php

echo pow( $_GET['n'], 2 );

?>
```

Comment: Even though this is a great solution, the OP asked for jQuery, not for Prototype.

Answer (score 9):

**Update:** Per the answer given by Yair Leviel, this answer is obsolete. Use a promise library, like jQuery.when() or Q.js.

---

I created a general purpose solution as a jQuery extension.  Could use some fine tuning to make it more general, but it suited my needs.  The advantage of this technique over the others in this posting as of the time of this writing was that *any* type of asynchronous processing with a callback can be used.

Note: I'd use Rx extensions for JavaScript instead of this if I thought my client would be okay with taking a dependency on yet-another-third-party-library :)

```
// jQuery extension for running multiple async methods in parallel
// and getting a callback with all results when all of them have completed.
//
// Each worker is a function that takes a callback as its only argument, and
// fires up an async process that calls this callback with its result.
//
// Example:
//      $.parallel(
//          function (callback) { $.get("form.htm", {}, callback, "html"); },
//          function (callback) { $.post("data.aspx", {}, callback, "json"); },
//          function (formHtml, dataJson) { 
//              // Handle success; each argument to this function is 
//              // the result of correlating ajax call above.
//          }
//      );

(function ($) {

    $.parallel = function (anyNumberOfWorkers, allDoneCallback) {

    var workers = [];
    var workersCompleteCallback = null;

    // To support any number of workers, use "arguments" variable to
    // access function arguments rather than the names above.
    var lastArgIndex = arguments.length - 1;
    $.each(arguments, function (index) {
        if (index == lastArgIndex) {
            workersCompleteCallback = this;
        } else {
            workers.push({ fn: this, done: false, result: null });
        }
    });

    // Short circuit this edge case
    if (workers.length == 0) {
        workersCompleteCallback();
        return;
    }

    // Fire off each worker process, asking it to report back to onWorkerDone.
    $.each(workers, function (workerIndex) {
        var worker = this;
        var callback = function () { onWorkerDone(worker, arguments); };
        worker.fn(callback);
    });

    // Store results and update status as each item completes.
    // The [0] on workerResultS below assumes the client only needs the first parameter
    // passed into the return callback. This simplifies the handling in allDoneCallback,
    // but may need to be removed if you need access to all parameters of the result.
    // For example, $.post calls back with success(data, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest).  If
    // you need textStatus or XMLHttpRequest then pull off the [0] below.
    function onWorkerDone(worker, workerResult) {
        worker.done = true;
        worker.result = workerResult[0]; // this is the [0] ref'd above.
        var allResults = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < workers.length; i++) {
            if (!workers[i].done) return;
            else allResults.push(workers[i].result);
        }
        workersCompleteCallback.apply(this, allResults);
    }
};

})(jQuery);
```

Comment: I have used this, and it works great!...but I do have one improvement: if you modify the final callback invocation to use "apply", then you get separate arguments to your callback instead of a single list of arguments:  i.e. workersCompleteCallback.apply(this,allResults);

Answer (score 7):

**UPDATE** And another two years later, this looks insane because the accepted answer has changed to something much better! (Though still not as good as Yair Leviel's answer using jQuery's `when`)

18 months later, I just hit something similar. I have a refresh button, and I want the old content to `fadeOut` and then the new content to `fadeIn`. But I also need to `get` the new content. The `fadeOut` and the `get` are asynchronous, but it would be a waste of time to run them serially.

What I do is really the same as the accepted answer, except in the form of a reusable function. Its primary virtue is that it is much shorter than the other suggestions here.

```
var parallel = function(actions, finished) {

  finishedCount = 0;
  var results = [];

  $.each(actions, function(i, action) {

    action(function(result) {

      results[i] = result;
      finishedCount++;

      if (finishedCount == actions.length) {
        finished(results);
      }
    });
  });
};
```

You pass it an array of functions to run in parallel. Each function should accept another function to which it passes its result (if any). `parallel` will supply that function.

You also pass it a function to be called when all the operations have completed. This will receive an array with all the results in. So my example was:

```
refreshButton.click(function() {

  parallel([
       function(f) { 
         contentDiv.fadeOut(f); 
       },
       function(f) { 
         portlet.content(f); 
       },
     ], 
     function(results) {
      contentDiv.children().remove();
      contentDiv.append(results[1]);
      contentDiv.fadeIn();
  });
});
```

So when my refresh button is clicked, I launch jQuery's `fadeOut` effect and also my own `portlet.content` function (which does an async `get`, builds a new bit of content and passes it on), and then when both are complete I remove the old content, append the result of the second function (which is in `results[1]`) and `fadeIn` the new content.

As `fadeOut` doesn't pass anything to its completion function, `results[0]` presumably contains `undefined`, so I ignore it. But if you had three operations with useful results, they would each slot into the `results` array, in the same order you passed the functions.

Answer (score 5):

you could do something like this

```
var allData = []
$.getJSON("/values/1", function(data) {
    allData.push(data);
    if(data.length == 2){
      processData(allData) // where process data processes all the data
    }
});

$.getJSON("/values/2", function(data) {
    allData.push(data);
    if(data.length == 2){
        processData(allData) // where process data processes all the data
    }
});

var processData = function(data){
     var sum = data[0] + data[1]
     $('#mynode').html(sum);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's an implementation using [mbostock/queue](https://github.com/mbostock/queue):

```
queue()
  .defer(function(callback) {
    $.post('/echo/json/', {json: JSON.stringify({value: 1}), delay: 1}, function(data) {
      callback(null, data.value);
    });
  })
  .defer(function(callback) {
    $.post('/echo/json/', {json: JSON.stringify({value: 3}), delay: 2}, function(data) {
      callback(null, data.value);
    });
  })
  .awaitAll(function(err, results) {
    var result = results.reduce(function(acc, value) {
      return acc + value;
    }, 0);
    console.log(result);
  });
```

The associated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/MdbW2/

Answer (score 3):

With the following extension of JQuery (to can be written as a standalone function you can do this:

```js
$.whenAll({
    val1: $.getJSON('/values/1'),
    val2: $.getJSON('/values/2')
})
    .done(function (results) {
        var sum = results.val1.value + results.val2.value;

        $('#mynode').html(sum);
    });
```

The JQuery (1.x) extension whenAll():

```
$.whenAll = function (deferreds) {
    function isPromise(fn) {
        return fn && typeof fn.then === 'function' &&
            String($.Deferred().then) === String(fn.then);
    }
    var d = $.Deferred(),
        keys = Object.keys(deferreds),
        args = keys.map(function (k) {
            return $.Deferred(function (d) {
                var fn = deferreds[k];

                (isPromise(fn) ? fn : $.Deferred(fn))
                    .done(d.resolve)
                    .fail(function (err) { d.reject(err, k); })
                ;
            });
        });

    $.when.apply(this, args)
        .done(function () {
            var resObj = {},
                resArgs = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
            resArgs.forEach(function (v, i) { resObj[keys[i]] = v; });
            d.resolve(resObj);
        })
        .fail(d.reject);

    return d;
};
```

See jsbin example:
http://jsbin.com/nuxuciwabu/edit?js,console

Answer (score 3):

The most professional solution for me would be by using [async.js](https://github.com/caolan/async) and Array.reduce like so:

```
        async.map([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], function (number, callback) {
            $.getJSON("/values/" + number, function (data) {
                callback(null, data.value);
            });
        }, function (err, results) {
            $("#mynode").html(results.reduce(function(previousValue, currentValue) {
                return previousValue + currentValue;
            }));
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

If the result of one request depends on the other, you can't make them parallel.

Comment: One doesn't depend on the other, but the end result depends on each being completed.

Comment: Since it's a simple mathematical operation between the data that you got back, then yes, you can use an out of scope variable to keep track of the data added. But in most cases this isn't a valuable solution for parallel requests that depend on each others data.

Answer (score 1):

Building on Yair's answer. 
You can define the ajax promises dynamically.

```
var start = 1; // starting value
var len = 2; // no. of requests

var promises = (new Array(len)).fill().map(function() {
    return $.ajax("/values/" + i++);
});

$.when.apply($, promises)
  .then(myFunc, myFailure);
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have an array of file name.

```
var templateNameArray=["test.html","test2.html","test3.html"];

htmlTemplatesLoadStateMap={};
var deffereds=[];
  for (var i = 0; i < templateNameArray.length; i++)
       {
        if (!htmlTemplatesLoadStateMap[templateNameArray[i]]) 
            {         
              deferreds.push($.get("./Content/templates/" +templateNameArray[i], 

                  function (response, status, xhr) {
                      if (status == "error") { } 
                        else {
                                $("body").append(response);
                               }
                         }));             
htmlTemplatesLoadStateMap[templateNameArray[i]] = true;
                       }
                  }
                                      $.when.all(deferreds).always(function(resultsArray) {   yourfunctionTobeExecuted(yourPayload);
                                });
```

Answer (score 0):

I needed multiple, parallel ajax calls, and the jquery `$.when` syntax wasn't amenable to the full `$.ajax` format I am used to working with.  So I just created a `setInterval` timer to periodically check when each of the ajax calls had returned.  Once they were all returned, I could proceed from there.

I read there may be browser limitations as to how many simultaneous ajax calls you can have going at once (2?), but `.$ajax` is inherently asynchronous, so making the ajax calls one-by-one would result in parallel execution (within the browser's possible limitation).