# Why aren't my JQuery .ajax requests being made in parallel?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to make two ajax requests in parallel using jQuery like this:

```
    var sources = ["source1", "source2"];

    $(sources).each(function() {
      var source = this;
      $.ajax({
        async: true,
        type: "POST",
        data: {post: "data", in: "here"},
        url: "/my/url/" + source,
        success: function(data) {
          process_result(data);
        }
      });
    });
```

I got the basic structure from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1060539/parallel-asynchronous-ajax-requests-using-jquery), but my requests still aren't being made in parallel.  "source1" takes a while to complete, and I can see on the server that the second request isn't made until the first is completed.

As far as I can tell, I don't have any other active requests, so I don't think it's a problem with the maximum number of parallel requests for the browser.  Am I missing something else here?

Comment: What do you see in Fiddler or Firebug?

Comment: I just re-tried my answer from that linked question and added a `sleep(4);` in the PHP page - still worked as expected.  All 4 requests fired at once and all took ~4 seconds to complete.

Comment: Backend was Catalyst running in my development sandbox without the --fork option.  The Net panel in Firebug didn't display the second request until the first had completed.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

jQuery does not queue AJAX requests. If you're **sure** you're not making any other requests your end, how about the server? Maybe it only has one worker?

**EDIT**: And just to make sure, I tested it with a script that launches 2 AJAX POST requests to a PHP script which sleeps for 5 seconds. They were not queued.

Comment: Seems like a server related issue.

Comment: Yes, was running my web server in my development sandbox without the --fork option, so it was only handling one request at a time.

Answer (score 8):

are you using php? are you using session_start()? sessions cannot be opened in parallel by multiple requests, to they will wait one after another to finish what they're doing.

Comment: Man, I love you !!!!!! Totally forgot this, lost 3 hours until your post ;-( A big thanks from south of france ^^

Answer (score 0):

What if you used $.post instead of $.ajax. This works for me.

```
var sources = ["source1", "source2"];

$(sources).each(function() {
  var source = this;
  $.post("/my/url/" + source, {post:"data", in:"here"}, function(data) {
      process_result(data);
  });
)};
```