# Get second ajax call response before previous ajax call

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have an ajax call which is used to perform a task and correspondingly update a table with the progress status.Now i have another ajax call to fetch the status from the table to show the task progress status to the user.The second call gets called repeatedly for every 2 seconds until the task is complete.But i could not show the task progress status to the user as the second ajax call keeps on loading till the response comes for the first ajax call.

I found a similar question in stackoverflow in the following link and it was suggested that it might be due to session lock and that using session_write_close() might work.I tried it and found no success.
[Prevent jQuery AJAX call from waiting for previous call to complete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23087423/prevent-jquery-ajax-call-from-waiting-for-previous-call-to-complete)

Is there a way to get the response for the second ajax call even while the first ajax call is still processing?

Comment: Post the relevant code here.

Comment: this sounds like a server side issue.

Comment: I tried the async:true but still the issue exists

Answer (score 0):

You can controller your Ajax functions flow using deferring concept of jQuery like

```
var defered = jQuery.Deferred();

function your_function(){
 //do something!
 defered.reslove()
 return defered.promise
} 
your_function.then(function(){
 //this will not run till your_function is done 
})
```

learn more at https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.Deferred/

Comment: But i need the second ajax call to be called for every 2s to get the table update..can this be done with deferred?