# 2 Updates Panels execution parallel

Tags: updatepanel

I have 2 update panels each with a refresh button to reload the contents.

When i click on the refresh button it takes 10 seconds to reload the contents, meanwhile before its contents are fully loaded, if user presses the refresh button 2, it stops the execution of first panel and starts execution of second panel.

Is it possible to execute 2 update panels in parellel?

Answer (score 0):

[Parallel asynchronous Ajax requests using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1060539/parallel-asynchronous-ajax-requests-using-jquery)

[How many concurrent AJAX (XmlHttpRequest) requests are allowed in popular browsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/561046/how-many-concurrent-ajax-xmlhttprequest-requests-are-allowed-in-popular-browser)