# Ajax call not running simultaneously in multiple browser window

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am using AJAX call to get the records. It will take 30 seconds to complete list the record. It is working. But if I open the same page in two windows in the browser, the first window complete the list and show after that the second window call the AJAX request and get the records.

I want to simultaneously ajax call the URL in two windows and get the results. How can I achieve this?

**Here is my code,**

```
var page="product.php?category=mobile&p=1";

$.ajax({
        url: page,
        type: 'GET',
        cache: false,
        processData:false,
        beforeSend: function(data) {
            return true;
        },
        success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
            $('#dataContent').html(data);
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
        }         
});
```

Comment: The two windows are doing this independently. Are you sure your backend is properly handling concurrent connections?

Comment: You can't, its an asynchronous call in two different threads. best you can do is depend on the js clock and only execute the `$.ajax` at a specific second *BUT* 1 call might still take longer than the other.

Comment: How to handle concurrent connections?? I just checked without database connection. It also getting same issue

Comment: I think your server should handle the thread parallel request. its not the issue in ajax.

Comment: I found the issue. Ajax is blocking the php session. it will not allow to start session_start() in php page.

Comment: @selvan, did you add this at the bottom of your PHP `session_write_close();`?

Comment: Related – [Two simultaneous AJAX requests won't run in parallel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15686572/two-simultaneous-ajax-requests-wont-run-in-parallel)

Comment: Yes Freedompride. It is working. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It's a Browser behaviour.

If you perform a GET request to exactly the same url - it will wait until the first ends. Just change urls by appending some different parameters like appendmillisecond to the end of you ajax call and see they will execute simultaneously. becase it will treat both the request as different request.