# Slowness while opening multiple tab in php application

Tags: php, session-variables

We have an application developed using php7.3.19.
There is slowness when we open new tabs. If one tab is opened and its loading, and we try to open next tab ,the new tab will not load until the first tab finished loading . So if one tab is opened and taking more time, then we have to wait till it completes loading to open new tab/functionality. We can open new functionality in new window/browser. So its is not related to the CPU/RAM.
Can someone put some light on this.

Comment: Are you using php sessions in your application? Take look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/15693029/4903314 and https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-write-close.php

Comment: PHP puts a lock on the session data files, as long as one script instance using the session is running, all others trying to access the same session will have to wait. Calling `session_write_close` as soon as possible can help with that.

Comment: The slow loading depends on your page data, make sure that there is no high loading sql queries used in that page @neethu