# jQuery parallel d3 objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, d3.js

Referring to the answer to this question:

[Parallel asynchronous Ajax requests using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1060539/parallel-asynchronous-ajax-requests-using-jquery)

Can we do something similar and have d3 objects in the body

Example from the question

```
var done = 4; // number of total requests
var sum = 0;

/* Normal loops don't create a new scope */
$([1,2,3,4,5]).each(function() {
  var number = this;
  $.getJSON("/values/" + number, function(data) {
    sum += data.value;
    done -= 1;
    if(done == 0) $("#mynode").html(sum);
  });
});
```

Comment: You should be able to simply replace `$.getJSON` with `d3.json` if that's what you're asking.

Comment: Thanks I will read about it and update this!

Answer (score 0):

As was mentioned in the comments, `d3.json` works roughly the same as `$.getJSON` so you could employ the same approach. However, there's a library [Queue.js](https://github.com/mbostock/queue) by the same author as D3 which formalizes the process for you and makes the results easier to process.

Here is the example from the [D3 release notes](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Upgrading-to-3.0#requests):

```
queue()
    .defer(d3.json, "us-states.json")
    .defer(d3.tsv, "us-state-populations.tsv")
    .await(ready);

function ready(error, states, statePopulations) {
  // display map here
}
```

I should also mention that d3 doesn't care how the data arrived, so if you are already planning to use jQuery in your page alongside d3 there's no real benefit to obtaining the data via d3's own methods. The main benefit of d3 having things like d3.json built-in is that you can avoid also loading something like jQuery if you don't otherwise need it.